# CASE in SELECT WHERE statement for stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to filter a table based on ManufacturerID in a stored procedure BUT when a null ManufacturerID is passed in I need all orders.

Can I do this in the WHERE statement so I don;t have to have the entire query written twice in my SP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WHERE
  @param IS NULL OR field = @param
```

But note, this gets very inefficient if you scale it up to search multiple columns.  (See http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Example of inefficient scaled up version...

```
WHERE
      (@param1 IS NULL OR field1 = @param1)
  AND (@param2 IS NULL OR field2 = @param2)
  AND (@param3 IS NULL OR field3 = @param3)
```

Comment: curious if you could `WHERE ManufacturerID = coalesce(@param,ManufacturerID)`

Comment: @vol7ron - Provided only `@param` is NULLABLE and not the field itself, then yes.  Your version will never return any record where ManufacturerID IS NULL.  Other than that, it behaves the same as my answer.

Comment: Just curious, haven't used SQL Server in a while - it seems Mark Bannister hopped on my comment :)  Given your statement, I'd tell him to do `WHERE coalesce(table.field,'') = coalesce(@param, table.field, '')`, but your solution is obviously the best choice

Comment: @vol7ron - That assumes that `''` isn't a legitimate value in the table already.  Also, be careful of implicit conversions; as in this case the field is likely to be an INT and not a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
where t.ManufacturerID = @ManufacturerIDParam OR @ManufacturerIDParam is null
```

Comment: @Downvoters Would you care to explain your vote in light of the fact that this answer is *virtually identical* to the accepted one?

Comment: +1 - In the face of injustice until the down-vote is explained, or removed

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WHERE table.field = coalesce(@param, table.field)
```

Comment: Unlikely as the OP mentions an ID field, but this does have a Corner Case to be aware of: This will never return records where `field IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

This can also lead to parameter sniffing issues. If possible, might want to clean up the nulls first instead?

Comment: That misses the point.  The OP is attempting to write a generic filter on the data.  If a value is specified, only return matching records.  Else, if no value is specified, return all records.